# Extracting information from Text Node js

Tags: node.js, nlp, extract

I am trying to build a system where recruiter will upload a doc file with Job Roles , Location , Experience , Title . the problem is every user will upload a different format document. Please Visit here to see [some sample docs](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AojFI4QIS0v1inuqn3JKukj2sCP0?e=KsX6Yj). 
I was thinking about creating dictionaries and saving key values pairs but is there any efficient and full-proof method or with NLP ?

is there any way i can get Location , Experience , Title , Roles in console separately ?

Comment: please post the code which you have already tried and facing issue with.

Comment: I have been planing on how to extract specific information as i have mentioned above , i have been reading some research papers but did not write a code first. i have posted this to get some suggestions about my problem. if it's okay ...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. **Spacy** library helps you in this matter. Just follow the below in order to download it and work for your problem. Happy AI with Node js.

https://towardsdatascience.com/natural-language-processing-with-spacy-in-node-js-87214d5547